# Bash: append multilines string with Brackets to file

Tags: bash, sed, concatenation, sh

I would like to add a multiline string to a file.

I tried with sed, but I don't know how to manage the brackets.

```
A='[program:process-0-10]
command=/usr/local/bin/process --config /home/10min/config.yaml --verbose
process_name=process-0-10
autorestart=true
startsecs=15
stopsignal=INT
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/0-10_stderr.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/0-10_stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=5MB"'

sed ${A} /etc/conf/supervisord.conf
```

Comment: where do you want to add it? if you want to just append to that file, use `echo "${A}" >> /etc/conf/supervisord.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers.

```
cat >>/etc/p/supervisord.conf <<EOF

blabla

EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Use redirections:

```
~$ A='....long string....'
~$ echo "$A"  >> file_to_append
~$ printf "%s\n" "$A" >> file_to_append
~$ while read -r line; do echo "$line" >> file_to_append; done <<< "$A"
```

Check what we've got:

```
~$ cat file_to_append
...long string...
...long string...
...long string...
```